# Unable to install packages with pip

Tags: python, pip, nexus

My build machine doesn't have internet connection. so i created proxy repository in nexus with name "proxy_repo" which is pointing to https://pypi.org/. and created ~/.pip/pip.config in build machine.

https://pypi.org/ is allowed to access from build machine through nexus.

content of the pip.conf is as below

```
[global]
trusted-host=MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com
index = https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/pypi
index-url = https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple
```

when i execute any pip command, say "pip -v install django" , i always getting below error. can some one please help?

```
    Collecting django
  1 location(s) to search for versions of django:
  * https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/
  Getting page https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/
  Looking up "https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com
  "GET /content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/ HTTP/1.1" 404 None
  Could not fetch URL https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://MyPrivate-nexusrepo.com/content/repositories/proxy_repo/simple/django/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for django
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before, solved mine by settings my date and time.. if the computer date and time is not current it prevents data fetching from Python.org

Comment: date and time settings are correct for the machine. but still i am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that often trips people up who are running in restricted environments is that access to both of these servers must be allowed through your corporate firewall:

https://pypi.org/

https://files.pythonhosted.org/

The reason for this is that requests made to the first URL often redirect to the second one for the content requested.